# PHP, remove trailing comma in array

Tags: php

There must be a kazillion topics and help related to this, but I cannot figure out how to implement anything to work with my setup.

HTML:

```
    <!-- SHOW/HIDE TEXT FIELD -->
    <!-- IF BITTEN ANIMAL="YES" or BITTEN "BOTH" Show Field -->
<div id="hidden_textfield10" style="display:none;">
    <p class="data_bold">What kind of animal</p><div class="data_small">What kind of animal has your pet bitten? Check all that apply:</div>
    <label for="Wild"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Wild" id="Wild" name="whatKindofAnimal[5]" />Wild</label><br />
    <label for="Bird"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Bird" id="Bird" name="whatKindofAnimal[4]" />Bird</label><br />
    <label for="Cat"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Cat" id="Cat" name="whatKindofAnimal[3]" />Cat</label><br />
    <label for="Dog"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Dog" id="Dog" name="whatKindofAnimal[2]" />Dog</label><br />
    <label for="Other-Animal"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" id="Other-Animal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" onclick="if(!this.checked) document.getElementById('otherKindofAnimal').value='' " />Other</label>
    <!-- IF BITTEN ANIMAL="Other" Show Field -->
<div class="Other-Animal" style="display:none;">
    <input class="form_style" type="text" placeholder="Please Specify" id="otherKindofAnimal" name="whatKindofAnimal[1]" />
</div>
    <!-- END "Other" Field -->
```

PHP:

```
<strong>What Kind of Animal:</strong> <?php $name = 
$whatKindofAnimal = implode(", ", $_POST['whatKindofAnimal']); {echo 
htmlspecialchars($whatKindofAnimal);} ?></p>
```

I know the name is the same for the last radio button and the textbox, but this works for my setup and is irrelevant with my dilemma. Disregard the HTML.

How do I correct the php to remove that last comma?

Thanks!!!
Tracy

Comment: Filter out the empty elements of the array before imploding: `implode(', ', array_filter($_POST['whatKindofAnimal']))`.

Comment: You Are Amazing! Thank you! Yes, I had read about the array_filter, along with a thousand other suggestions, but like I said, I had no idea of how to, or where to, add it; and add it correctly. Thank You! I'm hoping this was my last little dilemma with this form producing results correctly. Again, Thank You!!!

Comment: Not a complete duplicate of page linked above. I had read that post before and it did not help in my situation. The answer that deceze gave above fixed my problem easily w/2 words and a couple characters. Hope it helps someone else, too!

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use rtrim to remove the last comma.

Man page found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving each animal a specific position in the `whatKindofAnimal` array, you can just get the elements to fill the array where needed.  Note the use of `whatKindofAnimal[]` instead of `whatKindofAnimal[5]`

```
<label for="Wild"><input class="form_style" type="checkbox" value="Wild" id="Wild" name="whatKindofAnimal[]" />Wild</label><br />
```

Selecting Bird and Cat gives...

```
Array ( [0] => Bird [1] => Cat )
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use substrings:

```
 $FieldLength = StrLen($YourField);
 $YourField = SubStr($YourField, 0, $FieldLength-1);
```

Comment: You could also just use -1 as a parameter for substr().

Comment: I know its just for better understanding that i've made them separate